# Workflow to check if an item (task) exists in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, microsoft-planner

I have created a flow that creates a task in a SharePoint list after a task has been created in Planner. How can I improve this flow to firstly check if the task already exists in Sharepoint and therefore a new task must not be created?

I have created a string variable ("taskName") with the Planner task name and I am trying to see if it exists in the SharePoint task list.

[image]

However I am new to this and the condition keeps returning **FALSE** even though a task with the same name exists in SharePoint. I have used the following in the condition but I don't think it is correct:

[image]

Where

```
equals(body('Get_items'), variables('taskName'))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to apply filter query on Get items, like this:

[image]